# Angular 2 Injectable Interface?

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection, interface, inversion-of-control

Today I stumbled upon something that I didn't think would cause me trouble.

In Java and Spring, I can declare two beans that both implement a given interface, while in another class where they are injected I only work with the interface; this is in fact what I love with IoC: you don't really have to know what object you're working with, only it's *kind*.

So in my little Angular2/Typescript program, I was trying to do the same:

webapp.module.ts:

```
... 
import { WebAppConfigurationService } from './app/services/webapp.configuration.service';

@NgModule({
  ...
  providers: [WebAppConfigurationService]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

tnsapp.module.ts:

```
...
import { TnsConfigurationService } from './services/tns.configuration.service';

@NgModule({
   ...
   providers: [TnsConfigurationService]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Both of these modules are using a different provider: `TnsConfigurationService` or `WebAppConfigurationService`.

However, these two `@Injectable` services implement the same interface:

configuration.interface:

```
export interface IConfigurationService {
    ...
}
```

Finally, in one of my components, I use the injectable provided by one of these modules I showed you at the beginning:

```
import { IConfigurationService } from './configuration.interface';

export class HeroesService {

    constructor(private configurationService: IConfigurationService) { }
}
```

My expectation was that this last component being injected with the right service, even though the parameter is only explicitely defining the interface. Of course I get an error ("Error: Can't resolve all parameters for HeroesService")

Now, I don't expect an easy solution for this as it sounds as an architectural lack. But maybe someone can point me out to an alternative design?

Comment: Take a look at DI documentation https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html#typescript-interfaces-aren-t-valid-tokens

Comment: @yurzui I love it: "It's not Angular's fault." :-) Ok then, maybe there´s still a beautiful way to do it... I´ll read on later about this `OpaqueToken`

Comment: OpaqueToken is primarily intended for non-class providers (factories and values).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order for a provider to be injected, it should be registered as a provider. There's no `IConfigurationService` provider. And it cannot be a provider, because interfaces don't exist in compiled JS code.

The common practice for interfaces that are supposed to be used as provider tokens is to be abstract classes:

```
abstract class ConfigurationService { ... }

@Injectable()
class WebAppConfigurationService extends ConfigurationService { ... }

...
providers: [{ provide: ConfigurationService, useClass: WebAppConfigurationService }]
...
```

This recipe is commonly used by Angular 2 itself, e.g. [abstract `NgLocalization` class](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.4.7/modules/%40angular/common/src/localization.ts#L14) and [concrete `NgLocaleLocalization` implementation](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.4.7/modules/%40angular/common/src/common_module.ts#L26).

Comment: This looks really good, I'll keep you posted tomorrow morning (UTC)

Comment: Is this still up to date for angular 4 / 5? Coming from other languages that embrace DI such as Java I find it to be really strange having to use abstract classes as providers.

Comment: @PhilipFeldmann Yes, still totally relevant. To my knowledge, TS and its interfaces look strange enough to the ones with Java background, so no wonder.