# Angular Compiler throws Internal error: unknown identifier {}

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-compiler-cli

I am constructing my angular2 services like so

```js
import { OpaqueToken, ClassProvider } from "@angular/core";

export interface IService {
  // ... interface declaration
}

export class Service implements IService {
  // ... implementation goes here
}

export const IService = new OpaqueToken(Service.name);

export const ServiceProvider: ClassProvider = {
    provide: IService,
    useClass: Service,
};
```

This has worked and compiled wonderfully using ngc with angular 2.x.x
But after upgrading to angular 4.x.x, the ServiceProvider can no longer be ngc-compiled when used in a components 'providers' array. (Interestingly, the whole thing works when the provider is registered in an ngModule and NOT in a component.)

I get the following on my console:

> events.js:160
>         throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
>         ^ Error: Command failed: npm run ngc Error: Internal error: unknown identifier {}

Any ideas what's going on? I might convert my service to @Injectable() and not use the interface but that seems to run counter to the whole idea of using service interfaces :(

F.Y.I: I am using TypeScript 2.2.2

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1):

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/OpaqueToken-class.html

OpaqueToken was deprecated in 4.x, maybe try using the InjectionToken instead.

That's the first thing that came to mind.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll try this out asap and let you know.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, replacing OpaqueToken with InjectionToken did not solve the issue. 
What did however, was **using *abstract classes* instead of *interfaces* and *injection tokens***.

According to this answer [Angular 2 Injectable Interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42422549/angular-2-injectable-interface) it is a common recipe (also used by the angular team itself) to inject abstract classes and use them like interfaces.

```js
import { ClassProvider } from "@angular/core";

export abstract class IService {
  // ... interface declaration
}

export class Service implements IService {
  // ... implementation goes here
}

export const ServiceProvider: ClassProvider = {
    provide: IService,
    useClass: Service,
};
```