# Inject an Interface with Angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript, generics, interface

I'm trying to create a generic `DeleteableConfirmationComponent` that will allow me to show a confirmation dialog and invoke the `delete` method from any injected service implementing a `Deleteable` infterface.

To do so, I've created this Interface:

```
export interface Deleteable {
  delete(object);
}
```

and I have a service that implements it:

```
@Injectable()
export class LocalityService implements Deleteable {
  delete(locality): Observable<Locality> {
    // Delete logic.
  }
}
```

For the `DeleteableConfirmationComponent`, I've tried to inject the service using constructor:

```
export class DeleteableConfirmationComponent {
  constructor(
    public dialog: MdDialogRef<DeleteableConfirmationComponent>,
    @Inject(MD_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any,
    private service: Deleteable
  ) {}

  delete() {
    this.service.delete(this.object)
                .subscribe(() => {
                  this.dialog.close();
                });
  }
}
```

but unfortunately, I've got an error saying **it can't resolve all parameters for DeleteableConfirmationComponent**.

For now, I'm using the dialog data options, in order to pass my service:

```
confirmDelete(locality) {
  this.dialog.open(DeleteableConfirmationComponent, {
    data: {
      service: this.localityService
    }
  });
}
```

but it feels dirty and does allow any kind of service to be injected while I want to force service that implement the `Deleteable` interface.

I was thinking I could probably be better going with an `abstract class` but I'm more a fan of composition over inheritance.

Any idea or best practice advise?

Comment: `Unfortunately, you cannot use a TypeScript interface as a token` https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection#typescript-interfaces-arent-valid-tokens

Comment: abstract class is the best option here

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 Injectable Interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42422549/angular-2-injectable-interface)

Comment: The usage of abstract class has nothing to do with composition vs inheritance. A class can be used as an interface too. It doesn't necessarily have to be extended.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the comments, you can convert your interface to an abstract class:

```
export abstract class Deleteable {
  abstract delete(object);
}
```

Then in your providers you can map it to the real class:

```
providers: [{ provide: Deleteable, useValue: new LocalityService() }]
```

You may not like this approach, because it seems like now `LocalityService` must extend `Deleteable`. But what if `LocalityService` needs to extend some other class? Multiple inheritance is not allowed:

```
// Error: Classes can only extend a single class
export class LocalityService extends OtherClass, Deleteable { }
```

Or you may simply not like the fact that `Deleteable` will now show up in the prototype chain of `LocalityService`:

```
export class LocalityService extends Deleteable {
  delete(locality): void {
    // Returns true
    alert(this instanceof Deleteable);
  }
}
```

However, as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35990538/extending-vs-implementing-a-pure-abstract-class-in-typescript), TypeScript allows you to treat a class like an interface. So you can use `implements` with an abstract class.

```
export class LocalityService extends OtherClass implements Deleteable {
  delete(locality): void {
    // Returns false
    alert(this instanceof Deleteable);
  }
}
```

So for all intents and purposes, your abstract class is now behaving like an interface. It won't even show up in the prototype chain.

Comment: Wow I didn't know at all TypeScript allowed me to treat a class like an interface. I'll try some of these approach and let you guys know about it. Thanks

Comment: @lkartono I didn't know either - I was about to direct you to use a token as shown here: https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection#injectiontoken. But after some experimenting and research (see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35990538/extending-vs-implementing-a-pure-abstract-class-in-typescript) I saw that abstract classes were cleaner.

Comment: what if i want the provider(use value) to be retrieved from the parent component?

Comment: @snezed I'm not sure I understand - it seems you could inject the service into the parent component and then pass it down to the child via an `@Input` on the child component.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible with `InjectionToken` a replacement for the deprecated `OpaqueToken`

```
export const AuthenticationProvider = new InjectionToken(
  "AuthenticationProvider",
  { providedIn: "root", factory: () => new CognitoAuthenticationProvider() }
);

...

@Injectable()
export class CognitoAuthenticationProvider implements IAuthenticationProvider {

...

@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
export class AuthenticationService {
  constructor(
    @Inject(AuthenticationProvider)
    private authenticationProvider: IAuthenticationProvider,
    private http: HttpClient
  ) {}
```

Comment: What if the `CognitoAuthenticationProvider` has other dependencies that are resolved by DI? How do you resolve that in the InjectionToken?